# Was the teen drama Dawson's Creek named after the city Dawson Creek in northern British Columbia?

Tags: title, dawsons-creek

I know the show is set somewhere in the US, not in Dawson Creek and the title refers to a character named "Dawson" and presumably the setting  of the show includes a creek, but it's hard to believe it's just a coincidence the names are so similar. Was someone involved in the show from Dawson Creek (like how there's a city called "Ontario" in California)? Did a producer visit northern BC and just like the name?

Comment: There are multiple Dawson Creeks in the US.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Showrunner Kevin Williams has stated that he grew up near to a place called Dawson Creek, and that that is where the name of the show comes from.

> "Dawson came from a real place called Dawson's Creek where we all hung out as kids and partied,"
>
> [20 Surprising Facts You Probably Didn't Know About Dawson's Creek](https://www.eonline.com/news/907479/20-surprising-facts-you-probably-didn-t-know-about-dawson-s-creek)

And

> I started talking about growing up in North Carolina on a creek with my video camera, filming movies in the backyard and wishing to be Steven Spielberg. I just kept talking: it was about me and my friends. Paul said, “I like that. When you work that out, come back and pitch that to me.” I went home and stayed up all night long and wrote this 20-page outline.
>
> [Dawson's Creek turns 20](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/dawsons-creek-turns-20-kevin-williamson-reveals-teen-dramas-deepest-secrets-1075834/)

Williams' [biography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Williamson_(screenwriter)) indicates that he grew up in New Bern, North Carolina, less than 20 miles from a nearby body of water called [Dawson Creek](https://maps.app.goo.gl/tuy4wWoARFbnxTcy9).

Comment: There isn't a town called Dawson Creek in North Carolina, but there is a creek with that name less than 20 miles from New Bern. New Bern is where Williams was born, but then his family moved to Texas during his early years, returning to North Carolina for his high school years which is presumably the period that Williams was referring to since he said Dawson Creek was a place where he and his friends "partied", a term normally associated with teenagers.  His other statement "_I started talking about growing up in North Carolina on a creek_" is a bit incongruous and could be an exaggeration.

Comment: @StevePemberton It's not that much of a stretch to refer to your high school years as when you "grew up", since it can be a pretty significant part of your formative years. It's likely to be when you form many of your strongest bonds.

Comment: @Barmar - agreed but that's not what I was referring to. I was referring to "_growing up in North Carolina on a creek_" which implies living in a rural area in a house that is located alongside a creek.  Maybe they did live next to a creek when he was in high school, but without verification or knowing exactly where they lived during those years I consider the possibility that this statement was an exaggeration. We also don't know how close they lived to Dawson Creek, presumably close enough to drive there and party, but that doesn't really tell us anything, could be 1 mile, could be 20 miles.

Comment: @StevePemberton I see what you mean, "on a creek" sounds like their house was physically adjacent to the creek. I think he was just using figurative, flowery language to express how he felt about it, not intending it literally.

Comment: hmm, I grew up near the Elk River. Ask teens we swam in it, jumping from the bridge. The bridge was over the rapids. The town is called Elk Rapids. My show will be called Elk River. This is all essentially the same was what the showrunner has stated ... better ... it's all true. I don't doubt what he says. What is the problem here?